# Finite abelian group $G$, with $N \triangleleft G$ cyclic and $G/N$ cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $N \triangleleft G$. If both $N$ and $G/N$ are cyclic and $GCD(\vert N \vert,\vert G/N \vert)=1$ then $G$ is cyclic.

I don't know how to prove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $g$ generates $N$ and $h+N$ generates $G/N$.  Let $|N|=s$ and $|G/N|=t$, then $|G|=st$.  Suppose that $o(h)=n$, i.e., $nh=0$.

The following statements need to be fleshed out a bit.

- We may conclude that $n$ is a multiple of $t$.  In particular, $0+N=nh+N=n(h+N)$, so $n$ is a multiple of the order of $h$, i.e., $t$.  Therefore, $n=mt$ for some $m$.
- Consider $th$.  Since $th+N=t(h+N)=0+N$, we may conclude that $th\in N$.  If $th$ is a generator for $N$, then we may conclude that $h$ generates $G$: since $0=nh=m(th)$ and $th$ is a generator for $N$, it must be that $m$ is a multiple of $s$, so $st\mid n$.  Then, by Lagrange, we may conclude that $st=n$.
- Now, suppose that $th$ is not a generator for $N$.  Then $th=kg$ for some $0\leq k<s$, where $k$ is not relatively prime to $s$.  Our goal is to find an $a$ so that $kg=t(ag)$.  In other words, $k-ta$ is divisible by $s$.  Rewriting this, we have $k-ta\equiv 0\pmod{s}$.  Since $t$ is relatively prime to $s$, $t$ is invertible modulo $s$, so $a\equiv t^{-1}k\pmod s$.  Choose any such representative for $a$.
- In this case, $h+(1-a)g$ is a generator for $N$.  Namely, $t$ must divide the order of $h+(1-a)g$ by the argument above, but $t(h+(1-a)g)=th+tg-tag=tg$.  Since $t$ is relatively prime to $s$, by the theory of cyclic groups, $tg$ is a generator for $N$.